# Flutter ffmpeg : Video merger not working

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg, flutter-dependencies, video-editing

I have been trying to merge two videofiles using ffmpeg in flutter but a single videofile is merging two times and the sound of video is not working

This is my code

```
 final appDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
 String rawDocumentPath = appDir!.path;
 final outputPath = '$rawDocumentPath/videomerge.mp4';

 final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();

 String commandToExecute = '-y -i ${VideoFiles[0].path} -i ${VideoFiles[1].path} 
  -filter_complex \'[0:v][0:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]\' -map \'[out]\' $outputPath';

 _flutterFFmpeg.execute(commandToExecute).then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process exited with 
 rc $rc"));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi, can you put the result of `$rc` here?

Comment: D/flutter-ffmpeg(13681): FFmpeg exited with rc: 0